# Naudio - putting audio stream into values [-1,1]

Tags: c#, audio, arrays, naudio

Hi all I need to put my audio stream into values of [-1,1].

Can someone tell me a good approach. I was reading byte array and float array from stream but I don't know what to do next.

Here is my code:

```
float[] bytes=new float[stream.Length];
            float biggest= 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
                if (bytes[i] > biggest)
                {
                    biggest=bytes[i];
                }
            }
```

and I don't know how to put values into stream. Because byte is only positive values. And I need to have from [-1,1]

```
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Count(); i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] * (1 / biggest));
        }
```

Comment: what format is your audio in? Float, short? It is very unlikely that you are actually dealing with 8 bit audio.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code snippet, you're scaling the values, but using integers to do it. Have you tried just using the float values directly:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] /= biggest;      // scale bytes to 0..1
        bytes[i] *= 2;            // scale bytes to 0..2
        bytes[i]--;               // scale bytes to -1..1 
    }
```

Btw `bytes` is a more-than-slightly-confusing variable name for an array of floats.